# How do I do a parameter based publication in Meteor and remove old subscription document?

Tags: meteor

I want to implement a parameter based publication in Meteor but I am running into some problems.

Here is what I have.

As the user types the keyup event that subscribes to publication and passes the value of the input.

```js
'keyup #customerSearch': function(event, template){
    var keyword = template.find('#customerSearch').value;
    if(keyword){
      if(keyword.length >= 3){
        Meteor.subscribe('sessioncustomers', keyword); 
      }
    }
  }
```

The publication uses this keyword to return the records.

```js
Meteor.publish("sessioncustomers", function(keyword){
  if(keyword ){
    if(keyword.length >= 3){
      query.name  = new RegExp(regExpQuoted(keyword), 'i' );
      Customers.find(query);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }else{
    return null;
  }
});
```

The problem.
It works and documents are received except when the client changes the keyword or rather as the keywords changes the publication publishes additional documents that match the keywords but the client collection never removes the old documents.

How do I get the old documents that no longer match out of the client collection?

I thought that because the parameters of the subscription had changed that the non-matching documents would be unsubscribed and only the new matching documents would be subscribed.

Answer (score 9):

In your `keyup` callback you need to "unsubscribe" to the previous publication,
otherwise you'll keep the old documents.

```js
var sessionCustomersHandler = false;
'keyup #customerSearch': function(event, template) {
  var keyword = template.find('#customerSearch').value;

  if (keyword && keyword.length >= 3)
    var newSessionCustomersHandler = Meteor.subscribe('sessioncustomers', keyword); 

  if (sessionCustomersHandler)
    sessionCustomersHandler.stop();

  sessionCustomersHandler = newSessionCustomersHandler;
}
```

Moreover, don't forget to `check(keyword, String)` in your publish function, for security.

```js
Meteor.publish("sessioncustomers", function(keyword){
  check(keyword, String)

  if (keyword.length >= 3)
    return Customers.find({
      name: new RegExp(regExpQuoted(keyword), 'i' )
    });
});
```

Comment: The handle client side doesn't seem to support a stop method.

Comment: The var should be define outside the local scope. Updated.

Comment: I wonder, to increase performance, shouldn't you subscribe to the new subscription before unsubscribing to the old subscription? If the old and new subscription contains some same documents, these documents wont be send over the wire a second time, right?

Comment: @PeppeL-G Yes maybe you're right. Need to do some tests to verify this. Anyway I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PeppeL-G your note is extremely useful as it avoids *a lot* overhead on data intensive apps - thx mquandalle for updating accordingly. And meanwhile in 2015 this still seems to work that way. If anyone knows another solution a further update would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Make a local unnamed client collection

```
this.SessionCustomers = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

Call a server method to get the results you want.  Make the callback clear (remove all) and then insert to that local collection.

```
return Meteor.call('sessioncustomers', query, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    } else {
        SessionCustomers.remove({});
        var item, _i, _len;

        for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
           item = array[_i];
           SessionCustomers.insert(item);
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: `offer` and `offerCurrent` unused?

Comment: `array` should be `data`?

Comment: The changes happening server side  will not be propagated in real time with this solution.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was wondering how to clear the MiniMongo collection, and you just set it null. Fantastic. I've been searching for this for weeks!